# Извлечь текст от одной (или части) строки до другой (или части) строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Как извлечь текст  от одной (или части) строки  до другой (или части) строки?

Например. Исходный текст.

```
NewPP limit report
Parsed by mw1322
Cached time: 20170930075936
Cache expiry: 1900800
Dynamic content: false
CPU time usage: 0.064 seconds
Real time usage: 0.096 seconds
Preprocessor visited node count: 970/1000000
Preprocessor generated node count: 0/1500000
Post‐expand include size: 17704/2097152 bytes
Template argument size: 3368/2097152 bytes
Highest expansion depth: 23/40
Expensive parser function count: 0/500
Transclusion expansion time report (%,ms,calls,template)
100.00%   62.759      1 -total
 60.13%   37.735      1 Шаблон:Темы
 53.02%   33.275      1 Шаблон:Темы/тема
 48.46%   30.410      1 Шаблон:Темы/0
 24.76%   15.542      6 Шаблон:Иерархичен
 21.79%   13.672      3 Шаблон:Темы/все_учебники
 21.01%   13.187      2 Шаблон:Темы/1
 11.64%    7.305      6 Шаблон:Highlight
 10.62%    6.664      2 Шаблон:Темы/2
  9.98%    6.266      3 Шаблон:Книга
```

На выходе (произвольный диапазон)

```
             visited node count: 970/1000000
Preprocessor generated node count: 0/1500000
Post‐expand include size: 17704/2097152 bytes
Template argument size: 3368/2097152 bytes
Highest expansion depth: 23/40
Expensive parser function count: 0/500
Transclusion expansion time report (%,ms,calls,template)
100.00%   62.759      1 -total
 60.13%   37.735      1 Шаблон:Темы
 53.02%   33.275      1 Шаблон:Темы/тема
 48.46%   30.410      1 Шаблон:Темы/0
 24.76%   15.542      6 Шаблон:Иерархичен
 21.79%   13.672      3 Шаблон:
```

Вот так не получается

```
(visited)[\s.]*(Темы/все_учебники)
```

(*в скобках произвольные границы требуемого диапазона*)

Comment: надо задать некие условия оговаривающие как выглядит начало и окончание блока. по вашему вопросу не ясно на какие признаки надо опираться.

Comment: Если  у вас есть четкий маркер начала и конца, либо соответствующие позиции в строке - делается через substr и регулярки не нужны.

Comment: @Mike: я понимаю что для каждого произвольного диапазона (в этом примере) своя регулярка. Мне важно захватить несколько строк между A и B. Между словом в одной строке и между словом в другой строке, при этом строк между ними может быть несколько.

Comment: ну это зависит от того, как вы отмечаете середину блока. обычно пишется что то вроде `.*`, но точка обычно означает любые символы кроме перевода каретки. что бы она означала и перевод каретки то же у регулряки должен быть флаг 's' (singleline). он задается за пределами самой регулярки в зависимости от используемого языка (обычно после `/A.*B/s`). А может вы как то совсем по другому захватываете и поэтому ваша проблема в чем то другом. не видя регулярки которой вы пытаетесь захватить блок сказать ничего точно нельзя

Comment: @Mike: помогло вот так (без кавычек) - "\bvisited\b[\s\S.]*\bТемы/все_учебники\b". Вам спасибо за отклик.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло вот так:

```
\bvisited\b[\s\S.]*\bТемы/все_учебники\b
```

На выходе

```
visited node count: 970/1000000
Preprocessor generated node count: 0/1500000
Post?expand include size: 17704/2097152 bytes
Template argument size: 3368/2097152 bytes
Highest expansion depth: 23/40
Expensive parser function count: 0/500
Transclusion expansion time report (%,ms,calls,template)
100.00%   62.759      1 -total
 60.13%   37.735      1 Шаблон:Темы
 53.02%   33.275      1 Шаблон:Темы/тема
 48.46%   30.410      1 Шаблон:Темы/0
 24.76%   15.542      6 Шаблон:Иерархичен
 21.79%   13.672      3 Шаблон:Темы/все_учебники
```