# Java. Поиск в многострочном тексте при помощи регулярного выражения

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток, в Java я новичок, поэтому тапками не кидайте, если спрашиваю очевидную вещь. Однако, гугл мне в моём вопросе не смог помочь.
Есть текст вида:

```
"Белеет парус одинокой
В тумане моря голубом!..
Что ищет он в стране далекой?
Что кинул он в краю родном?..."
```

И тут у меня возникает два вопрос:
1) Как поместить этот текст в одну переменную.
2) Если это невозможно (размещение многострочного текста в переменной), то как реализовать поиск по регулярке, если, к примеру мне требуется данный отрывок:

```
 голубом!..
    Что
```

Т.е. должно срабатывать регулярное выражение вида:

```
[а-я]+[!.]+\n[а-яА-Я]+
```

Comment: Java-программа твоя будет читать файл .txt?

Comment: как-то задавался этим [вопросом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/731892/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8/731912#731912)

Comment: У Лермонтова в оригинале, однако, нет восклицательного знака, так что эта программа на аутентичном тексте не сработает :)

Comment: @Antonio112009 , верно, она будет читать .txt :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массивы текстовых данных, в т. ч. состоящие из отдельных строк, могут существовать в `Java` как в виде наборов строковых элементов (массив, `ArrayList` и т.п.), так и в виде отдельной строки, содержащей символы перенеоса строк (`"\n"` или `"\r\n"`, в зависимости от системы). Если данные читаются из файла, то, как правило, они читаются методом `readLine()` одного  из классов-потомков `Reader` , по одной строке за раз, и в этом случае со строками можно поступать как с элементами массива.

Если текст хранится в виде набора строк, то все эти строки можно объединить используя `StringBuilder` (последовательно в цикле добавляя к нему строку за строкой) или методом String.join(). Второй вариант может быть чуть удобнее, но он может оказаться дороже в смысле памяти и быстродействия.

Когда строки объединены тем или иным способом, можно использовать регулярку для поиска в объединенной строке. Пример кода ниже показывает объедининие строк обоими методами и описание единой строки, содержащей символы переноса строк.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Ru_So_756552 {

    public static String[][] testData = {

        {   "Белеет парус одинокой\n" + // array of 1 string 
            "В тумане моря голубом!..\n" + 
            "Что ищет он в стране далекой?\n" + 
            "Что кинул он в краю родном?..." },

        {   "Мой дядя самых честных правил, \n" + 
            "Когда не в шутку занемог, \n" + 
            "Он уважать себя заставил \n" + 
            "И лучше выдумать не мог" }, 

        {   "Белеет парус одинокой",    // Array of 4 strings 
            "В тумане моря голубом!..", 
            "Что ищет он в стране далекой?", 
            "Что кинул он в краю родном?..." },

    }; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([\\wА-Яа-я]+!\\.{2}\\n[\\wА-Яа-я]+)");
        for (String[] data: testData) {

            System.out.println("*** Data:");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (String s: data) {
                System.out.println(s);
                sb.append(s + "\n"); // Concatenate using StringBuilder
            }

            String joint = String.join("\n", data); // Concatenate using join()
            System.out.println("*** Joint data:\n" + joint);

            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(sb);
            System.out.println("*** Found:\n" + (m.find()? m.group(1) : "nothing... :("));
            m = pattern.matcher(joint);
            System.out.println("*** Found in joint:\n" + (m.find()? m.group(1) : "nothing... :(") + "\n");   

        } // for (String[] data: testData) {
    } // public static void main(String[] args) {

} // public class Ru_So_756552
```

Comment: Ну и можно не объединять строки, а искать совпадения в конце одной строки и в начале следующей, типа `if (strings[i].endsWith("ом!..") && strings[i+1].startsWith("Что ")) ...`. Если строки хранятся отдельно, то это может быть быстрее.

Comment: Благодарю за дельный и развёрнутый ответ! Со стрингбилдером работать умею и это, действительно единственный вариант в виду большого количества обрабатываемого текста. Так что осталось дело за малым - реализовать задуманное :)

Answer (score 0):

Я не умею работать с регулярными выражениями, но, как я понимаю, программа должна выглядеть вот так. Проверь её

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class stackOver{

    public static String readLine(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException{
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        String text = "";
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            text = text + scanner.nextLine() + " ";
        }
        scanner.close();
        return text;
    }

    public static void findWord(String input) {
        Pattern regexp = Pattern.compile("[а-я]+!+..+[а-яА-Я]+[ ]+[и]");
        Matcher m = regexp.matcher(input);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.print(m.group());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(readLine("test.txt"));
        findWord(readLine("test.txt"));
    }
}
```

Comment: `text = text + scanner.nextLine() + " ";` -- это ***очень*** дорогое удовольствие, надежный способ сделать тормоз из мощного компьютера. К тому же результат не будет содержать переносов строки.

Comment: @m.vokhm +++, StringBuilder надо использовать

Comment: @Санаев в своем ответе я так и сказал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756552/java-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/756572#756572